# How to log Protractor text elements with VS Code debugger?

Tags: debugging, promise, protractor, visual-studio-code

I have VS Code configured with a debug task like this for Protractor debugging:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Tests (Local)",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/config/protractor/protractor.conf.override.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Say I have this test:

```
it('description', function () {
    expect(this.myPageObject.title.getText()).toEqual('My PO Title');
})
```

This all works fine but now I'm tring to debug this with VS Code. I've set a breakpoint on the `expect` line and debugging itself works just fine. But now I want to print (to the debug console) the value of `this.myPageObject.title.getText()`.

I know that `getText` and most other Protractor methods return promises and that I need to resolve them, but I'm not sure how. Here's what I've tried:

```
this.myPageObject.title.getText()
ElementFinder {browser_: ProtractorBrowser, then: (fn, errorFn) => { … }, parentElementArrayFinder: ElementArrayFinder …}

this.myPageObject.title.getText().then(console.log)
ManagedPromise {flow_: ControlFlow, stack_: null, parent_: ManagedPromise …}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, this sucks, right? It seems like top-level `await` should work. But nope.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no nice solution comes to my mind

1) Try to put breakpoint into callback -

```
let titleText = this.myPageObject.title.getText().then(text => {
    return text // Breakpoint here, so you can observe text variable in debug panel
})
expect(titleText).toEqual('My PO Title');
```

2) You might try to debug using `> protractor --elementExplorer` terminal command, which starts protractor in interactive more, where you can observe your actions step-by-step

3) You might try to use `await this.myPageObject.title.getText()` in right in vs code debugging terminal on breakpoint. Didn't tried this, but might work.

This is one of the problems of Promise Manager - hard debugging, so thats why it will be deprecated soon. More info : http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html  and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969

Comment: 1) IMO that defeats the whole purpose of using the debugger if I have to change my code all the time just for debugging. 2) I don't seem to have access to my tests context that way. 3) Didn't work, `await` is not defined.